# How to create Apache service with custom httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I have my `custom-httpd.conf` file `c:\apache\conf` Am wondering how do I use this `custom-httpd.conf` file instead of `httpd.conf` file to create Apache service in windows

Tried the below command but didnt work

```
httpd.exe -k start -k config ..\conf\custom-httpd.conf -n "Apachefacade"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to list down your customization in one of the file say `my.conf`. And as described on the [Apache Site](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/platform/windows.html#winsvc)

If you need to have specifically named configuration files for different services, you must use this:

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName" -f "c:\files\my.conf"
```

Good Luck!